# Generate nested JSON using array elements as keys

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a file with the below contents and a shell variable with some keys. I want to create nested JSON using all keys.
eg:

```
file.json:
{
    "name":"..",
    "value":".."
}
```

shell variable which contains list of keys:

```
values=('one' 'two' 'three')
```

I want to create a variable like below:

```
{
   "all":{
        "one":  {
            "name":"..",
            "value":".."
        },
        "two":  {
            "name":"..",
            "value":".."
        },
        "three":  {
            "name":"..",
            "value":".."
        }
   }
}
```

I tried to pass the values are `--arg` to JQ, but it didnt work. JQ version: 1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer versions of JQ populates an internal array (`$ARGS.positional`) with arguments given after `--args` on command-line, you can use it.

```
jq '{all: [{($ARGS.positional[]): .}] | add}' file --args "${values[@]}"
```

On older versions, you can use this approach:

```
printf '"%s"\n' "${values[@]}" |
    jq '{all: [{(inputs): .}] | add}' file -
```

But note that this is not as reliable as the above one, I highly recommend updating JQ.